# Animations higher in the SwiftUI view hierarchy overriding nested animations

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI `View` which has a repeating animation `onAppear`. When that view is used within a view hierarchy that includes another animation, the higher-level animation overrides the nested one. Consider the following basic example:

```swift
struct Example: View {
  @State private var opacity: Double = 0

  var body: some View {
    Text("Example")
      .opacity(opacity)
      .onAppear() {
        withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
          self.opacity = 1
        }
      }
  }
}
```

When this is used in a context similar to the following, the repeating animation does not run. If I remove the animation from this stack, the repeating animation works as expected.

```swift
struct Parent: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Example()
    }
    .animation(.easeInOut)
  }
}
```

How can I structure this to allow both animations to work? When children are added to the `VStack` they should animate as per that view's animation property, but they should retain their own defined animations too. Is there some documentation on animations and the boundaries between them that I have missed somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to link your internal animation to specific state variable, then it will be independent.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
  var body: some View {
    Text("Example")
      .opacity(opacity)
      .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), 
          value: opacity)            // << here !!
      .onAppear() {
          self.opacity = 1
      }
  }
```